# How to pass Parcelable array to fragment and Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working with custom parcelable class. I need to pass this class as array to another activity and new fragments. I googled, but I found arrayList but not arrays. Please mind that I need to pass arrays not Array lists. How to achieve that? Please mind again, performance is a big issue. So any solutions with less performance consumption is very welcome.

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: check my edited comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the write answer

```
// write parcelable array
final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
MyParcelable[] myArray = new MyParcelable[10];
arguments.putParcelableArray("key"myArray);

// read parcelable array
MyParcelable[] myArray = (MyParcelable[])getArguments().getParcelableArray("key");
```

Comment: were is MyParcelable class

Comment: It is any class implementing Parcelable (interface)…

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your arrayList as below snipts.

```
 TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putSerializable("parsedData", (Serializable)mTestModelList);
 testFragment.setArguments(args);
```

And Get these parcable data in Model as like below:

```
mTestModelList = (List<TestModel>)getArguments().get("parsedData");
```

YES, Serialisation is slow bit than Parcelable.

And you can implement that using [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)

Of course, the ParcelWrapper can be added to an Android Bundle to transfer from Activity to Activity using this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("example", Parcels.wrap(example));
```

And dereferenced in the onCreate() method:

```
Example example = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("example"));
```

You can get more detail of performance related to Parcelable vs Serializable [here](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/).

Comment: Yes.. Because Serialization is too slow in comparison to Parcable.

Comment: Please look at my anser.

Answer (score 0):

use like following class of your parcealble array

```
public class ParcelableLaptop implements Parcelable {
private Laptop laptop;

public Laptop getLaptop() {
    return laptop;
}

public ParcelableLaptop(Laptop laptop) {
    super();
    this.laptop = laptop;
}

private ParcelableLaptop(Parcel in) {
    laptop = new Laptop();
    laptop.setId(in.readInt());
    laptop.setBrand(in.readString());
    laptop.setPrice(in.readDouble());
    laptop.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class
            .getClassLoader()));
}

/*
 * you can use hashCode() here.
 */
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Actual object Serialization/flattening happens here. You need to
 * individually Parcel each property of your object.
 */
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeInt(laptop.getId());
    parcel.writeString(laptop.getBrand());
    parcel.writeDouble(laptop.getPrice());
    parcel.writeParcelable(laptop.getImageBitmap(),
            PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE);
}

/*
 * Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR,
 * which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface.
 * Used to un-marshal or de-serialize object from Parcel.
 */
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableLaptop> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableLaptop>() {
    public ParcelableLaptop createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ParcelableLaptop(in);
    }

    public ParcelableLaptop[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParcelableLaptop[size];
    }
  };
}
```

now make Arraylist of ParcelableLaptop and put in the bUndle with argument

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("laptop", parcelableLaptopArray);
```

Where parcelableLaptop is your Arraylist of the Model. And to get the List:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

 ArrayList<ParcelableLaptop> parcelableLaptop = (ParcelableLaptop) intent
         .getParcelableArrayListExtra("laptop");
```

Comment: ParcelableLaptop parcelableLaptop = (ParcelableLaptop) intent
         .getParcelableExtra("laptop");
It seams a single object. But I need for object array.

Comment: I have edited the code pls check this... if you get any problem then do let me know

Comment: Your code looks awsum. Please check it. Also I need for array not arrayList. Code must be like this: ParcelableLaptop[]

Comment: Please look at my anser.